# Cannot pass string parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I searched through this site and found some topic about my problem but still cannot make this work....

I am simply trying to retrieve data from a SQL Server database using a stored procedure.
I am passing one parameter that is a `SqlDbType.Varchar(50)` type, but I get back a SQL error:

> *Procedure or function 'WyszukajPrzesylki' expects parameter '@Nazwisko', which was not supplied.*

What am I doing wrong? Store procedure works if I test it in SSMS ...

It even works when I type

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("WyszukajPrzesylki @Nazwisko = Example", con);
```

You are my last hope guys... I've already lost 2 days with this problem and cannot get any further... don't have any problems with inserting and updating records using c# ... just  this....

So here is the code of SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WyszukajPrzesylki] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Nazwisko varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
-- SELECT * FROM Przesylki WHERE (NazwiskoAdresata = @NazwiskoAdresata)
SELECT * FROM Przesylki WHERE (Przesylki.NazwiskoAdresata = @Nazwisko)
END
```

and action of the button:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Monitoring_PrzesylekString1);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("WyszukajPrzesylki", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter parametrNazwisko = new SqlParameter("@Nazwisko", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
parametrNazwisko.Value = "Dziubak";
com.Parameters.Add(parametrNazwisko);

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ad.Fill(ds, "id");
con.Close();
DataTable datatableA = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "id";
```

Comment: `...SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.WyszukajPrzesylki @Nazwisko = 'Example';"), con);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing almost everything right - up to this line:

```
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);
```

You're creating a SQL data adapter, but only based on the SQL statement of the `com` - you should use this instead:

```
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
```

You should use the whole `com` object you've already set up with parameters and everything - **not** just it's SQL statement text!

Comment: This line was wrong

     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);

Instead it should be like this

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(com);


Can't belive I spent 16 hours on this!!! :(